# Creating a cumulative sum column with_order in R

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, tidyverse, query-parser

I'm working alongside a SQL tutorial using queryparser and tidyquery in R. This has been going well until I was asked to do:

```
SELECT ... SUM(new_vaccinations) OVER (PARTITION BY location) as vaccinations_to_date
```

Tidyquery reported that it did not support `OVER` functions so I am trying to replicate the `OVER (PARTITION BY...)` function with dplyr.

This led me to `with_order(order_by =...` in dplyr. Now I'm struggling with getting the `fun =` to allow me to create a cumulative sum column.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(queryparser)
library(tidyquery)

mydf <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2021-06-01", '2021-06-02','2021-06-03','2021-06-04',
                                  '2021-6-01','2021-6-02','2021-6-03','2021-6-04',
                                  '2021-6-01','2021-6-02','2021-6-03','2021-6-04')),
                   location = c('United States','United States','United States','United States',
                                'Canada','Canada','Canada','Canada','Mexico','Mexico','Mexico','Mexico'),
                   new_vaccinations = c(100,98,32,50,99,34,97,53,35,101,97,56))

test <- mydf %>% 
  mutate (total_vax = with_order(order_by = location, fun = cumsum(new_vaccinations), x = desc(location)))
```

This gives me the error

```
could not find function "fun"
```

Am I looking down the wrong rabbit hole when it comes to how to recreating `OVER(PARTITION BY...)`? If so what is a better option?
Or am I missing how to properly use `with_order(order_by =...)`?

If it is not clear, my goal is to create a new column that keeps a running total of vaccinations for each separate location.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I got sums of vaccinations by location just using test <- mydf %>% group_by(location) %>% summarise(new_vaccinations)

Comment: How does your target data look like, @JamesWheeler?

Comment: To answer Roman and clarify for @Kylie R. this was what I ran to get the answer I wanted thanks to Simon's answer:
`test1 <- mydf %>%
  select(date, location, new_vaccinations) %>%
  group_by(location) %>%
  arrange(location, date) %>%
  mutate(new = cumsum(new_vaccinations)) %>%
  arrange(location, date) %>%
  select(date, location,  new_vaccinations, new)
view(test1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PARTITION BY` aspect of SQL can often be done in dplyr using `group_by`.

And the `ORDER BY` aspect of SQL can often be done in dplyr using `arrange`.

Consider this R code:

```r
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, cyl) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  arrange(mpg) %>%
  mutate(new = cumsum(mpg)) %>%
  arrange(cyl, mpg) %>%
  select(cyl, mpg, new)
```

Is equivalent to this SQL:

```sql
SELECT cyl
    ,mpg
    ,SUM(mpg) OVER (PARTITON BY cyl ORDER BY mpg) AS new
FROM mtcars
```

Comment: Thank you for this Simon. I responded in a comment on the original question with the final code that I used to solve the problem. If I run into any issues when moving to a larger dataset, would you mind me sending them your way? This was very helpful!